# jsreport failing on looking up extensions

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ember.js, jsreport

So I recently started working on a linux machine (ubuntu 16.04) and followed the installation instructions here http://jsreport.net/downloads/. When I run npm start --production I get

```
    2016-09-13T16:51:57.134Z - info: Initializing jsreport in production mode using configuration file prod.config.json
2016-09-13T16:51:57.138Z - info: Setting process based strategy for rendering. Please visit http://jsreport.net/learn/configuration for information how to get more performance.
2016-09-13T16:51:57.146Z - info: Searching for available extensions in /home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/
2016-09-13T16:51:57.152Z - info: Extensions location cache not found, crawling directories
2016-09-13T16:51:57.317Z - error: Error occured during reporter init Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/ember/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-2yGnPLMA.tmp/optimo-ui/config'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:801:18)
    at /home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/node_modules/jsreport/node_modules/jsreport-core/lib/util/util.js:51:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.exports.walkSync (/home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/node_modules/jsreport/node_modules/jsreport-core/lib/util/util.js:44:10)
    at /home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/node_modules/jsreport/node_modules/jsreport-core/lib/extensions/locationCache.js:50:20
From previous event:
    at /home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/node_modules/jsreport/node_modules/jsreport-core/lib/reporter.js:90:8
From previous event:
    at Reporter.init (/home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/node_modules/jsreport/node_modules/jsreport-core/lib/reporter.js:69:30)
    at Reporter.reporter.init (/home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/node_modules/jsreport/lib/extendInit.js:8:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ross/rifiniti/optimo_ui/server.js:1:85)
```

And I have no idea why. It was working fine on mac but now it is looking for this non-existent tmp file in ember. I'm at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you solve a problem post the answer as an answer to your own question, not as an edit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

All I had to do was remove the tmp directory in ember and it worked.